# Postgresql: many one-to-one tables instead of one big table

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, scalability

Is it viable to use many tables that are in one-to-one relationship instead of one big table?
The main goal is to be able to easily change schema when needed. Create/drop a  table when needed, instead of a new column or changing a column.

How scalable will this be with Postgresql?

Comment: Will you be retrieving most of these tables together most of the time? In that case: every JOIN will cost you.

Comment: That's the idea. Maybe not "most of the time" but often

Comment: This makes sense if you e.g. update the "core" data very seldomly but update the others frequently. When you almost always _read_ all the tables together then this won't give you any performance gain for reading.

Comment: What sort of schema changes do you need to make? I wonder whether you would be better served with JSON or Hstore storage.

Comment: Actually I'm migrating away from json storage as I need consistency and durability and better tooling for backups and exploration (by non-programmers)